# Css list style. How to align css list styles?

Tags: html, css

[image]

we want to proper alignment. How to proceed with css?? Proper left alignment text, with multiple line text.

Comment: do you have html code ? fiddle perhaps would be usefull

Comment: Your desired result is the default list-item behaviour. Can you show us your current HTML and CSS?

Comment: add css   text-align:justify

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/R5BK2/

Answer (score 0):

The CSS property you are looking for is called `list-style-position`, although that is set to `outside`, the value you want, by default.

```
ul {
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

Of course, if you just add an image to the front of your text, that's not gonna help. Instead, set this:

```
ul {
    list-style-position: outside;
    list-style-image: url(/path/to/image.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like background image too,

```
li {
  background: url('yourArrowimg.png') left top no-repeat;
  padding-left: 20px;
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, because what you want is the default behavior, as mentioned by @oGeez

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GLt5B/)

```
  <div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>CSS</li>
        <li>XHTML</li>
        <li>Semantics</li>
        <li>Accessibility</li>
        <li>Usability</li>
        <li>Open Web Standards</li>
        <li>PHP</li>
        <li>Typography</li>
        <li>Grids</li>
        <li>CSS3</li>
        <li>HTML5</li>
        <li>UI</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
#wrapper {
    width:100px;
}

li{ 
    list-style-image: url("arrow.png");
}
```